# Errors while compiling allegro library program on gcc

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I've tried installing allegro library on my system.I didn't get any error while installing the library, but it seems that something went wrong while installation. My code along with the errors I'm getting while compiling the program:

```
    /* testprog.c */

#include <allegro.h>

void init();
void deinit();

int main() {
init();

while (!key[KEY_ESC]) {
/* put your code here */
}

deinit();
return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN()

void init() {
int depth, res;
allegro_init();
depth = desktop_color_depth();
if (depth == 0) depth = 32;
set_color_depth(depth);
res = set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640, 480, 0, 0);
if (res != 0) {
allegro_message(allegro_error);
exit(-1);
}

install_timer();
install_keyboard();
install_mouse();
/* add other initializations here */
}

void deinit() {
clear_keybuf();
/* add other deinitializations here */
}


Errors I'm getting:

$ gcc testprog.c -o testprog `allegro-config --cflags --libs`
testprog.c: In function ‘init’:
testprog.c:26:1: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

I've followed instructions given on these links for installing the library and compiling my program:

[Instructions for installing allegro on ubuntu](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Ubuntu_and_Allegro_5)

[Instructions for compiling programs written in allegro](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Build/Linux)

Comment: The question is missing the important text. There are no links. Please check the question again.

Comment: oh! sorry! my mistake! let me edit it

Comment: what is `END_OF_MAIN()` ?

Comment: It is predefined macro,in order to maintain cross-platform compatibility, you have to put this macro at the very end of your main function, please check this:
https://www.allegro.cc/manual/4/api/using-allegro/end_of_main

Comment: It's for allegro 4, right?

Comment: @int_ua No, it was for allegro 5, but I think this question is not so relevant now, it was asked 1.5 yrs ago.

Answer (score 1):

`allegro_message()` outputs a message, using a `printf()` format string.

The error is in the line:

```
allegro_message(allegro_error);
```

Change it to:

```
allegro_message("%s\n", allegro_error);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error :(

Comment: Let's continue this discussion on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8022/discussion-between-green-and-still-a-kid)